# How to run Alarm in background in Android Oreo and above

Tags: broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, background-process, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I am new to android and working on android Alarm application, my application is working fine on android below oreo but not above . I am stuck in using Broadcast receiver to fire Alarm at the given time by user  in background on devices Android Oreo and above. I have read so many articles but not get clear answer. There is so many restrictions in Android Oreo and above to run background services. So what should i use to run alarm in background . Please suggest me which one of these should i use for backround process,  Broadcast Reciever, job Scheduler, AlarmManager(using right now) or any other (if any). Please help me out . Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the best practice it depends on your need . Use alarm manager if you want to be specific about time. When Alarm received, start a foreground service and register your broadcast receivers (if you need broadcast receivers).

You can register your receivers without a foreground service, but they sometimes work instable due to the resource management of the Android.

If your operation don't need to be time specific, then you should use WorkManager.

Look this link for further information
https://developer.android.com/guide/background